# Adding distance in the data command makes the command fail

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to making the command block detect the dragon phase within 100 blocks using this command:

```
execute store result score @a Dragon run data get entity @e[type=minecraft:ender_dragon,limit=1,sort=nearest,distance=1..100] DragonPhase
```

For some reason, it doesn't work because of `distance=..100` and it works when I remove it. Any ideas what is causing this issue?

Comment: The command blocks looks for the dragon at a max of 100 blocks from -the command block-, is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, I made it so it can detect any ender dragon within 100 blocks

Comment: What is the error message you receive? Please edit your post to show us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my issue because the function didn't know the location to execute so I added `execute at <target>` and that fixes the issue.

Comment: Don't forget to click the check mark to approve this answer. It will let others know that this question is Solved.